# Synchronise content between an iOS and Android file

Tags: javascript, android, ios, git

Let's consider there is a class named `AnalyticsConstants.swift` in the iOS project and `AnalyticsConstants.kt` in the Android project. Each file contains an enum as follows:

```swift
// AnalyticsConstants.swift
enum EventType {
  case buttonTap = "BUTTON_TAPPED"
  case dropDownTapped = "DROPDOWN_BUTTON_TAPPED"
}
```

```kotlin
// AnalyticsConstants.kt
enum class EventType(val value: String) {
  BUTTON_TAP("BUTTON_TAPPED"),
  DROPDOWN_TAPPED("DROPDOWN_BUTTON_TAPPED")
}
```

To ensure synchronization between the enums in both platforms, we considered exploring Kotlin Native as a solution, but it could negatively impact the developer experience. Same for React Native and Protobuf. We are thinking to implement a lightweight script or linter that runs every n days. This script would check for any differences in the enum values and notify if any parity-breaking changes are found between the iOS and Android platforms.

**Any other possible solutions or suggestions? Any links which can help me write the custom linter?**

Comment: A possible solution would be to create a simple data file that defined the events (perhaps a .csv with columns for the swift case name, the Android case name and the string representation). A script (or two) could parse this file and produce the swift and Android source code. The data file would be your source of truth and a custom build step would ensure the actual code used in the apps was kept up to date.

Comment: Thank you @GeoffHackworth! Looks like a much better idea than a linter.

Comment: You do not need a custom build check to test this. Just write a unit test (for each platform) that reads the file and then compares with an iteration of the enum values.

Comment: @hlovdal In that case how it will validate what values are added on the other platform? Major problem here is events are not in sync between the platforms

Comment: Given that a file contains all the enum values, you "just" need to have this file shared/synced between the projects. That should be possible with `git submodule update --remote`.